# No architecture in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable - previous answers didn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

I recently added a framework to my xcode project (SquareReaderSDK.framework) and am now getting this issue whenever I try to upload or validate it:

`No architecture in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable`

This runs fine locally on all devices (I've tested on an iPad running the latest OS and on an older one running 9.3.5) - this only happens after Archiving and trying to Validate / Upload.

I've found a number of other people with similar issues but none of the fixes seem to do it for me:

- The name and bundle id are correct
- Re-starting XCode, re-running `pod install`, cleaning the project didn't change anything

I have managed to get it to upload via a series of bizarre steps that will need to change for production because they limit the architectures I can deploy to:

- I had to make the deploy target the device that was plugged in rather than `Generic iOS Device`. I know I'll need to figure out a way to not have to do this or I can't download it on my older iPad
- I had to set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `Yes`. This will need to change as well I believe or I'll run into the same issue as the first bullet
- Under linked frameworks with libraries I selected `Optional` instead of `Required`. This will need to stay like this in order to get it to work at all on older devices (this framework only works on iOS 11+).
- Under **Build Phases / Embed Frameworks** I deselected `Code Sign On Copy` for the `SquareReaderSDK.framework`. I don't know if this will need to change, I added it because others were suggesting removing the build phase would solve this issue

  - I had to add a run script as the final build phase as one of the instructions in the Square Reader Setup for iOS: `FRAMEWORKS="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}"
    "${FRAMEWORKS}/SquareReaderSDK.framework/setup"`

Any variation on this combination of steps seems to get me the original error. Any ideas?

I can share any additional information that could be helpful

Comment: Update: if I up the Deployment Target from 9 to 11 I can get it to work with the Generic iOS Device. But any lower and I get this error. I know the SquareReaderSDK.framework only works on iPad running 11+ but I am able to run it on an iPad with 9.3.5 by setting it to Optional in the Linked Frameworks and Libraries section. Any reason it should be different when archiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue ended up being specific to the SquareReaderSDK.framework. There's a setup script that Square created that is required to run it on a device. During the archive process, however, part of that script deletes architectures that the SquareReaderSDK doesn't support. I had to comment out those lines to get the archive & validation process to work properly and then handle the unsupported architectures in code